# Cannot see the variable In my own JQuery plugin's function

Tags: jquery, plugins, datepicker

I am writing a jQuery plugin of my own. And I got some strange which make me confused.

I am using jQuery UI datepicker with my plugin.

```
;(function($){
    var newMW = 1,
        mwZIndex = 0;

    // IgtoMW contructor
    Igtomw = function(elem , options){
        var activePanel,
            lastPanel,
            daysWithRecords,
            sliding; // used to check the animation below is executed to the end.

        // used to access the plugin's default configuration
        this.opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.igtomw.defaults, options); 

        // intial the model window
        this.intialMW();
    };

    $.extend(Igtomw.prototype, {

        // intial model window
        intialMW : function(){

            this.sliding     = false;
            //this.daysWithRecords  = [];

            this.igtoMW = $('<div />',{'id':'igto'+newMW,'class':'igtoMW',})
                .css({'z-index':mwZIndex})   // make it in front of all exist model window;
                .appendTo('body')
                .draggable({ containment: 'parent' , handle: '.dragHandle' , distance: 5 });

            //var igtoWrapper = igtoMW.append($('<div />',{'class':'igtoWrapper'}));
            this.igtoWrapper = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoWrapper'}).appendTo(this.igtoMW);
            this.igtoOpacityBody = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoOpacityBody'}).appendTo(this.igtoMW);

            //var igtoHeaderInfo = igtoWrapper.append($('<div />',{'class':'igtoHeaderInfo dragHandle'}));
            this.igtoHeaderInfo = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoHeaderInfo dragHandle'})
                                    .appendTo(this.igtoWrapper);

            this.igtoQuickNavigation = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoQuickNavigation'})
                                      .css({'color':'#fff'})
                                      .appendTo(this.igtoWrapper);

            this.igtoContentSlider = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoContentSlider'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoWrapper);

            this.igtoQuickMenu = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoQuickMenu'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoWrapper);

            this.igtoFooter = $('<div />',{'class':'igtoFooter dragHandle'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoWrapper);

            //  append to igtoHeaderInfo
            this.headTitle = this.igtoHeaderInfo.append($('<div />',{'class':'headTitle'}));

            //  append to igtoQuickNavigation                             
            this.igQuickNav = $('<div />', {'class':'igQuickNav'})
                                .html('登录')
                                .appendTo(this.igtoQuickNavigation);   

            //  append to igtoContentSlider
            this.igInnerPanelTopMenu =  $('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanelTopMenu'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoContentSlider);

                this.igInnerPanelTopMenu.append('<div class="igInnerPanelButtonPreWrapper"><a href="" class="igInnerPanelButton Pre" action="" style="background-image:url(images/igto/igInnerPanelTopMenu.bt.bg.png);"></a></div>');
                this.igInnerPanelTopMenu.append('<div class="igInnerPanelSearch"><input type="text" name="igInnerSearch" /><a href="" class="igInnerSearch">搜索</a></div>' ); 
                this.igInnerPanelTopMenu.append('<div class="igInnerPanelButtonNextWrapper"><a href="" class="igInnerPanelButton Next" action="sm" style="background-image:url(images/igto/igInnerPanelTopMenu.bt.bg.png); background-position:-272px"></a></div>' );                                        

           this.igInnerPanelBottomMenu =  $('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanelBottomMenu'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoContentSlider);    

           this.icWrapper =  $('<div />',{'class':'icWrapper','id':'igto'+newMW+'Panel'})
                                        .appendTo(this.igtoContentSlider);

           this.icWrapperCotentPre  = $('<div class="slider pre"></div>').appendTo(this.icWrapper);
           this.icWrapperCotentShow = $('<div class="slider firstShow "></div>').appendTo(this.icWrapper);
           this.icWrapperCotentnext = $('<div class="slider next"></div>').appendTo(this.icWrapper);


            this.initialPanel();                    
            this.initialQuickMenus();
            console.log(this.leftPad(9));                    

            newMW++;
            mwZIndex++;


            this.igtoMW.bind('mousedown',function(){

                var $this = $(this);

                //alert($this.css('z-index') + ' '+mwZIndex);
                if( parseInt($this.css('z-index')) === (mwZIndex-1) )
                    return;

                $this.css({'z-index':mwZIndex});
                mwZIndex++; 
                //alert(mwZIndex);
            });   
        },
        initialPanel : function(){
            this.defaultPanelNum = this.opts.initialPanel;
            this.activePanel = this.defaultPanelNum;
            this.lastPanel   = this.defaultPanelNum;


            this.defaultPanel = this.loadPanelContents(this.defaultPanelNum);

            $(this.defaultPanel).appendTo(this.icWrapperCotentShow);    
        },
        initialQuickMenus : function(){
            // store the current element
            var obj = this;

            var defaultQM    = this.opts.initialQuickMenu;

            var strMenu      = '';
            var marginFirstEle = '8';


            $.each(defaultQM,function(key,value){
                //alert(key+':'+value);
                if(marginFirstEle === '8'){
                    strMenu += '<a href="" class="btPanel" panel="'+key+'" style="margin-left: 8px;" >'+value+'</a>'; 
                    marginFirstEle = '4';
                }
                else{
                   strMenu += '<a href="" class="btPanel" panel="'+key+'" style="margin-left: 4px;" >'+value+'</a>'; 
                }       
            });
                        //  append to igtoQuickMenu
            this.igtoQMenu = $(strMenu).appendTo(this.igtoQuickMenu); 


            this.igtoQMenu.bind('click',function(event){

                event.preventDefault();
                var element = $(this); 

                if(element.is('.active')){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    $(obj.igtoQMenu).removeClass('active');
                    element.addClass('active');                     
                }

                    var d = new Date();
                    var year = d.getFullYear();
                    var month = obj.leftPad( d.getMonth() );
                    var inst = null;



                if( obj.sliding === false){
                    console.log(obj.lastPanel);

                    var currentPanelNum = parseInt(element.attr('panel'));
                    obj.checkAvailability();
                    obj.getDays(year,month,inst,currentPanelNum);
                    obj.slidePanel(currentPanelNum);



                    obj.activePanel = currentPanelNum;
                    console.log(obj.activePanel); 
                    obj.lastPanel = obj.activePanel;
                    obj.icWrapper.find('input').val(obj.activePanel);
                }

            });
        },
        initialLoginPanel : function(){

            var obj = this;

            this.igPanelLogin = $('<div />',{'class':"igPanelLogin"});
            this.igEnterName  = $('<div />',{'class':"igEnterName"}).appendTo(this.igPanelLogin); 
            this.igInput      = $('<input type="text" name="name" value="秦海翔" />').appendTo(this.igEnterName); 
            this.igtoLoginBtWrap = $('<div />',{'class':"igButtons"}).appendTo(this.igPanelLogin);
            this.igtoLoginBt = $('<a href="" class="igtoLoginBt" action="OK" >确定</a>\
                                  <a href="" class="igtoLoginBt" action="CANCEL" >取消</a>\
                                  <a href="" class="igtoLoginBt" action="ADD" >添加用户</a>').appendTo(this.igtoLoginBtWrap); 

            this.igtoLoginBt.bind('click',function(event){

                event.preventDefault();
                var elem = $(this);
                var action = elem.attr('action');
                var userName = obj.igInput.val();

                obj.loadRootMenu();  
            });

            return  this.igPanelLogin;

        },
        initialWatchHistory : function(){
            var obj = this; // for thirt part plugin used
            if(this.sliding === false){
            this.watchHistory = $('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanelSlider'}).append($('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanel_pre'}).addClass('igInnerPanel'))
                            .append($('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanel'}).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',defaultDate: '2010-12-01' ,showWeek: true,firstDay: 1,                                                                                              
                                                                                                    //beforeShow:setDateStatistics(),
                                                                                                    onChangeMonthYear:function(year, month, inst) { 
                                                                                                      var panelNum = 1;
                                                                                                      month = obj.leftPad(month);
                                                                                                      obj.getDays(year,month,inst,panelNum);

                                                                                                  } ,  
                                                                                                  beforeShowDay: obj.checkAvailability,
                                                                                                  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                                                                                                    obj.checkAvailability();

                                                                                                  }
                                                                                                }).append($('<div />',{'class':'extraMenu'})) )
                            .append($('<div />',{'class':'igInnerPanel_next'}).addClass('igInnerPanel'));

            return this.watchHistory; }   
        },
        loadPanelContents : function(panelNum){
            switch(panelNum){
                case 1:
                    alert('inside loadPanelContents')
                    return this.initialWatchHistory();
                break;
                case 2:
                    return this.initialWatchHistory();
                break;
                case 3:
                    return this.initialWatchHistory();
                break;
                case 4:
                    return this.initialWatchHistory();
                break;
                case 5:
                    return  this.initialLoginPanel();
                break;
            }
        },
        loadRootMenu : function(){

            var obj = this;        
            var mainMenuPanel = $('<div />',{'class':'igRootMenu'});
            var currentMWId =  this.igtoMW.attr('id');
            this.activePanel = 0;

            $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .pre').
               queue(function(next){

                  $(this).
                     html(mainMenuPanel).
                     addClass('panelShow').
                     removeClass('pre').
                     attr('panelNum',0);
                     next();
               }).
               queue(function(next){
                  $('<div style="width:0;" class="slider pre"></div>').
                      prependTo('#'+currentMWId+'Panel').animate({width:348}, function(){

                          $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:last').remove()
                          $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:last').replaceWith('<div class="slider next"></div>');

                          $('.btMenu').remove();  // remove bottom quick menu
                          obj.sliding = false;
                          $(this).removeAttr('style');
                      });

                  $('.igtoQuickMenu .active').removeClass('active');      
                  next();
              });     
        },
        slidePanel : function(currentPanelNum){

            var currentMWId =  this.igtoMW.attr('id');
            var obj = this;
            //alert(obj.loadPanelContents(currentPanelNum));
            if( this.activePanel > currentPanelNum){

                $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .pre').
                   queue(function(next){
                       alert('inside slidePanel')
                      //var initialDate = getPanelDateStatus(panelNum);
                      //console.log('intial day in bigger panel '+initialDate)
                      $(this).
                         html(obj.loadPanelContents(currentPanelNum)).
                         addClass('panelShow').
                         removeClass('pre').
                         attr('panelNum',currentPanelNum);
                         $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .next').remove();

                         next();
                   }).
                   queue(function(next){

                      $('<div style="width:0;" class="slider pre"></div>').
                          prependTo('#'+currentMWId+'Panel').animate({width:348}, function(){

                              //$('#igto1Panel .slider:last').find(setPanel(currentPanelNum)).datepicker('destroy');
                              $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:last').empty().removeClass('panelShow').addClass('next').removeAttr('panelNum');
                              $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:last').replaceWith('<div class="slider next"></div>')

                              obj.sliding = false;console.log('inuse inside animation: '+obj.sliding);
                              $(this).removeAttr('style');
                          });


                      next();
                   });
            }
            else{  ///// current panel num smaller than next

                $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .next').
                   queue(function(next){

                      $(this).
                         html(obj.loadPanelContents(currentPanelNum)).
                         addClass('panelShow').
                         removeClass('next').
                         attr('panelNum',currentPanelNum);
                         $('<div class="slider next">empty</div>').appendTo('#'+currentMWId+'Panel');

                         next();
                   }).
                   queue(function(next){

                      $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .pre').animate({width:0}, function(){

                                        $(this).remove();
                                        //$('#igto1Panel .slider:first').find(setPanel(currentPanelNum)).datepicker('destroy');
                                        $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:first').empty().removeClass('panelShow').addClass('pre').removeAttr('panelNum').removeAttr('style');
                                        $('#'+currentMWId+'Panel .slider:first').replaceWith('<div class="slider pre"></div>')

                                        obj.sliding = false;
                                        console.log('inuse inside animation: '+obj.sliding);
                                    });

                      next();
                   });

            }

        },
        getDays : function(year,month,inst,panelNum){

            var obj = this;
            // depend on the mysql query condition
            var table_of_record = 'moviewh';//getTable(panelNum);
            var date_of_record = 'watching_date';//getTableDateCol(panelNum);
            var date_to_find = year+'-'+month;
            var node_of_xml_date_list = 'whDateRecords';//getXMLDateNode(panelNum);
            var user_id = '1';//getLoginUserId();

            //var daysWithRecords = [];
            // empty array before asigning
            this.daysWithRecords.length = 0;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "include/get.date.list.process.php",
                data:({ table_of_record : table_of_record,date_of_record:date_of_record,date_to_find:date_to_find,user_id:user_id,node_of_xml_date_list:node_of_xml_date_list }),
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,  // force broser don't cache the xml file
                async: false,  // using this option to prevent datepicker refresh 异步NO
                success:function(data){

                    // had no date records
                    if(data === null)
                        return;

                    obj.daysWithRecords = data; 
                }

            });

            //setPanelDateStatus(year,month,panelNum);
            console.log('call from getdays() ' + this.daysWithRecords);
        },
        checkAvailability : function(availableDays) { //

            var i; 
            var checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', availableDays);
             //console.log( checkdate); 

//            for(var i = 0; i < this.daysWithRecords.length; i++) { 
//                
//               if(this.daysWithRecords[i] == checkdate){
//                 
//                   return [true, "available"];
//                }
//            }
            //console.log('inside check availablility '+ this.daysWithRecords);  //return [true, "available"];
            console.log(typeof this.daysWithRecords)
            for(i in this.daysWithRecords){
                //if(this.daysWithRecords[i] == checkdate){
                   console.log(typeof this.daysWithRecords[i]); 
                   //return [true, "available"];
                //}    
            }
            return [true, "available"];
            //return [false, ""];

        },
        leftPad : function(num) { 
            return (num < 10) ? '0' + num : num; 
        }

    });

    $.fn.igtomw = function(options){

        // Merge options passed in with global defaults
        var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.igtomw.defaults , options);

        return this.each(function() {
                    new Igtomw(this,opt);
               });   
    };

    $.fn.igtomw.defaults = {
        // 0:mainMenu   1:whatchHistor   2:requestHistory    3:userManager
        // 4:shoppingCart   5:loginPanel
        initialPanel : 5,  // default panel is LoginPanel  
        initialQuickMenu : {'1':'whatchHIstory','2':'求片记录','3':'用户管理','4':'购物记录'} // defalut quick menu 
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**usage:**

```
$('.openMW').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="">').igtomw();

})
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="taskBarAndStartMenu">
    <div class="taskBarAndStartMenuM">
        <a href="" class="openMW" >启动IGTO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="taskBarAndStartMenuO"></div>
</div>
```

In my work flow:

when I click the **"whatchHistory"** button 【the event which defined inside **initialQuickMenus : function()**】, my plugin would load a panel with **JQuery UI datepicker** applied which days had been set to be availabled or not.

I am using the function **"getDays()"** to get the available **days list** and stored the data inside **daysWithRecords**, and final the UI datepicker's function **"beforeShowDay()"**　called the function **"checkAvailability()"** to set the days.

the variable **"daysWithRecords"** was declared inside **Igtomw = function(elem , options)** and was initialized inside the function **getDays()**

I am using the function **"initialWatchHistory()"** to initialization and render the JQuery UI datepicker in the web.

**My problem** is the function **"checkAvailability()"** cannot see the variable **"daysWithRecords"**.The firebug prompts me that **"daysWithRecords"** is **"undefined"**.

this is the first time I write my first plugin. So ....

Thank you very much for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your Igtomw declaration let daysWithRecords be a local variable. In getDays function, you can get data by => 'obj.daysWithRecords = data;' berfore console.log(...). In checkAvailability  function, you don't give any value to daysWithRecords before console.log(...).